# What is the full verse uttered by Dharmaraja after the Mahabharata war which contains this phrase - जयोऽयम् अजयाकरो?

Tags: mahabharata, sanskrit, vyasa

Dharmaraja expresses dismay at the end of the Mahabharata war with this line:

```
जयोऽयम् अजयाकरो
```

I'm unable to find where this is uttered and what the complete verse is.

Comment: There is no such verse in the southern recession of the mahabharata

Answer (score 1):

Yudhishthira says these words after finding all their sons dead.

> जयॊ ऽयम अजयाकारॊ

> jayo 'yam ajayākāro

> This our victory has assumed the shape of defeat. Our victory, therefore, has ended in defeat!

From the Kisari Mohan Ganguli version of Mahabharata:

https://sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs10010.htm

> 11 हत्वा भरातॄन वयस्यांश च पितॄन पुत्रान सुहृद्गणान
> बन्धून अमात्यान पौत्रांश च जित्वा सर्वाञ जिता वयम

> 12 अनर्थॊ हय अर्थसंकाशस तथार्थॊ ऽनर्थदर्शनः
> **जयॊ ऽयम अजयाकारॊ** जयस तस्मात पराजयः

> 13 यं हित्वा तप्यते पश्चाद आपन्न इव दुर्मतिः
> अक्थं मन्येत विजयं ततॊ जिततरः परैः

> 11 hatvā bhrātṝn vayasyāṃś ca pitṝn putrān suhṛdgaṇān
> bandhūn amātyān pautrāṃś ca jitvā sarvāñ jitā vayam

> 12 anartho hy arthasaṃkāśas tathārtho 'narthadarśanaḥ
> **jayo 'yam ajayākāro** jayas tasmāt parājayaḥ

> 13 yaṃ hitvā tapyate paścād āpanna iva durmatiḥ
> akthaṃ manyeta vijayaṃ tato jitataraḥ paraiḥ

Eng. tr:

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10010.htm

> Having slain brothers and friends and sires and sons and well-wishers, and kinsmen, and counsellors, and having vanquished them all, we ourselves are vanquished at last! Misery looks like prosperity and prosperity looks like misery! This our victory has assumed the shape of defeat. Our victory, therefore, has ended in defeat! Having won the victory, I am obliged to grieve as an afflicted wretch. How, then, can I regard it as a victory? In reality, I have been doubly defeated by the foe. They for whose sake we have incurred the sin of victory by slaying our kinsmen and friends, alas, they, after victory had crowned them, have been vanquished by defeated foes that were heedful